# Xlwings Import Function error in visual basic

Tags: excel, vba, xlwings

when i am clicking on import functions option in xlwings excel addins it shows that

```
Run-time error '1':
Could not load xlwings64-0.30.2.dll from either of the following folders:
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3 , C:\ProgramData
```

[error message of visual basics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbSFG.png)

i try to import python functions in excel

Comment: https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/troubleshooting.html

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)